# How do i properly use this code to replace all occurrences of more than one decimal element with a single one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, replace

I built a calculator in ReactJs. And i would like to prevent the user from entering more than one decimal element eg `2..3` Anytime a user does this i'd like to replace all the decimal elements with a single one. So `2..3` would become `2.3`

This is how i am trying to achieve this but it doesnt work

```
if (calc.input.match(/\.{2,}/g)) {
  setCalc(calc.input.replace(/\.{2,}/g, "."));
}
```

`setCalc` is the hook i'm using to change state.

Comment: Better just mark the input as invalid instead of interfering with the typing user.

Comment: Firstly, always give more info than "it doesn't work". Secondly, it's probably better to either simply mark it as invalid and prevent them from submitting or calculating or whatever, or checking for a second decimal *before* updating the state value. Since doing it after could be confusing as it might not be clear which is the right decimal point to keep and which ones should be removed

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this, the regex seems to work fine. What are `calc` and `setCalc`, can you show the entire code please? It's weird that you have this extra `.input` property access though.

Comment: This would have been my original approach. But i'm doing it as one of the freeCodeCamp certification projects and one of the requirements is to prevent the user from being able to do this.

Comment: @Berto99 The proper approach would be `/…/.test(calc.input)`, but really the OPs code already works in this regard.

Comment: @Bergi technically it doesn't, if you try the regex on like `2.3.` it won't remove second decimal point. It's looking for consecutive ones only

Comment: @Jayce444 that's actually true. Thank you for pointing that out. I would have given more information if i understood why it didn't work. I tested it by logging out a string everytime more than one decimal is input. It kept logging with every input after the second decimal value was entered

Answer (score 1):

This should help. It basically keeps the input from happening if we already find a decimal in the string already when hitting a key.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
text.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  // if the text already includes a decimal, and our current key is a decimal, prevent the new key from being added.
  if (text.value.includes('.') && e.key == '.') e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try to rewrite this approach in ReactJs

Comment: With this approach a user can still input an invalid value by pasting it into the field.

Comment: @JemiSalo correct, in which case there would need to be an event for `input` or `change` as well. However, the OP asked about a user typing in a value.

Answer (score -1):

Remembered that strings are immutable and so to change the value of `calc.input` I would have to reassign it to itself. And so this approach worked for me for this particular use case.

**Note that it doesnt prevent input in the form 9.9.9**

```
if (calc.input.match(/\.{2,}/g)) {
  setCalc(calc.input = calc.input.replace(/\.{2,}/g, "."));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
var S='456...........876';

S=S.replace(/\.+/g,'.');  // I escape the period with a slash and place the + next to it to mean "all".

document.write(S);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate. I had already used this approach. It didn't work.